# Java Textarea ScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jscrollbar

I have created a textarea, and i need a scrollbar applied to the textarea when necessary (when the text gets too long down and it cant be read anymore).

this is the code i have written, but for some reason, the scrollbar doesnt really come up?

```
    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setBounds(10, 152, 456, 255);
    textArea.setBorder(border);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    sbrText = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    sbrText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    panel_1.add(textArea);
```

Comment: Asked a second time for god-know's what reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624305/using-a-jscrollpane-with-a-jtextarea

Answer (score 1):

- You have to remove the code line that makes the `JTextArea` have absolute size on the screen due to using `setBounds()`. This makes it *non-resizable*, and `JScrollPane` works only if its content is *resizable*.

  ```
  // wrong
  textArea.setBounds(10, 152, 456, 255);
  ```
- Please read [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) and [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) tutorial; please run examples from both tutorials.

Comment: what do you mean? you mean i need to get rid of Final? my textarea has to be final, as i am using that later in the code, and the code later requires the textarea to be final. is there any way, i can keep it final and add a scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

see this

```
 import javax.swing.*;

    public class TestFrame extends JFrame

{
    JTextAreaWithScroll textArea;

    public TestFrame ()
    {
        super ("Test Frame");

        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize (300, 300);

        textArea = new JTextAreaWithScroll (JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        add (textArea.getScrollPane ());
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                TestFrame f = new TestFrame ();
                f.setVisible (true);
            }
        });
    }
}


class JTextAreaWithScroll extends JTextArea
{
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public JTextAreaWithScroll (int vsbPolicy, int hsbPolicy)
    {
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane (this, vsbPolicy, hsbPolicy);
    }

    public JScrollPane getScrollPane ()
    {
        return scrollPane;
    }
}
```

from 
http://forum.html.it/forum/showthread/t-1035892.html

Comment: This relies on the frame's content pane having a default `BorderLayout` and default destination `CENTER`.

Answer (score 0):

You added the TextArea to a parent twice (scrollPane and panel).
Change your last line to

```
panel_1.add(sbrText);
```

Comment: I have tried that, but then the textarea isnt available on the frame anymore?

Comment: There's no frame in your example code. But for me it works this way. Maybe you have to change the layout of the panel.

Comment: Well i have a frame and stuff, hence its not working your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `preferredSize` and the `viewportSize` are the same. The scrollpane will size itself with the preferred size of the `textArea`, and this can cause the scrollbars to disappear if the preferred size of the text area is large enough to display itself.

Again, please read the [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) and [JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#sizing) tutorials.

```
textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(456, 255));
textArea.setPreferedScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(456, 255));
```