# Using a JScrollPane with a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jscrollbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Textarea ScrollPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624014/java-textarea-scrollpane)

I have code for a scrollbar to appear in a textarea but it doesnt really work. Any suggestions?

```
    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setBounds(10, 152, 456, 255);
    textArea.setBorder(border);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    sbrText = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    sbrText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    panel_1.add(textArea);
```

Comment: **What** "doesn't work"? Please describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Now why did you waste everyone's time by asking this question twice? This is very thoughtless of you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the `JScrollPane` to the panel, **not** the `JTextArea`.  So instead it should be:

```
panel_1.add(sbrText);
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesnt work. the textarea isnt visible in the frame anymore when i do that

Comment: Well no way to know without seeing how your JPanel is created and added to the JFrame.  Anyway, you asked this question twice.  You should ask on the other question, rather than creating two of the same question.